# Putting private information on Public PaaS?

Tags: openshift, public, paas

If I put my private information into any Public PaaS (I'm currently using OpenShift environment), would it be open to Public? or to employees of the company? I fail to understand how public is a Public PaaS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your information that you upload or deploy to your gear on OpenShift is private to your gear(s), Red Hat/OpenShift employees will not access the data on your gear unless you give us your permission.

Comment: Good to know, but what is public about Public PaaS then?

Comment: That you can tell anyone on the internet to go visit your website, and that anyone can sign up and use it.  Private PaaS would be hosted behind a corporate firewall etc

Answer (score 0):

if you use GIT for this, you can deploy gitolite on virtual private server for this.
I think that a lot of collaboration tools can be deployed on VPSes or, if you do not trust it, you can bye your own PC and use it as server. I do the same, i have Rapsberry PI pc with some git repos and tasktracker / calendar/ LDAP applicaitons, that is used by me and my team.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Rather than jumping towards the private alternatives, I want to understand to what extent these Public PaaS made the information publicly available. For example, when I created an account on OpenShift, I saw a clear message on my main repository domain: "this area is for your eyes only." But this is a Public PaaS? So, where and how is that public?